# Apostrophe force exiting String

Tags: jquery, string, apex

I have an input box which is populated with a string from an apex method. If I use an apostrophe in the String, I receive an 'Unexpected Identifier' error.

Heres the code:

```
            $('#textInput').append(
                $('<input>').addClass('ui-input-note').attr('placeholder', 'Notes')
                    .val('{! CurrentNote  }')
            );
```

This is what displays in the console:

```
            $('#textInput').append(
                $('<input>').addClass('ui-input-note').attr('placeholder', 'Notes')
                    .val('Jim's dog')
            );
```

I'm assuming the apostrophe is exiting the string. How do I get around this?

Other than using " ".

Cheers

Comment: You should be able to escape these characters by using \

Comment: But I dont want a user to have to type Jim\'s dog

Comment: @Daft What's the actual problem you're trying to solve with the code? If you're having problems with user input containing a single-quote it sounds like you're doing something wrong.

Comment: well yes I am doing somthing wrong, and I'm trying to fix it. I can't really explain it any better than I did in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follow:

1. catch the `escape` character  on its key in event

   ```
    $(document).keypress(function(event){
          alert(String.fromCharCode(event.which)); 
     })
   ```
2. append the \ with `escape` characters to the user input.

   ```
    //Append text to input element
     function jQ_append(id_of_input, text){
         if(text=='`'){
              text='\`';
          }
          $(id_of_input).val($(id_of_input).val() + text);
      }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the escape() (and then the unescape() ) function.

Here more info and examples: [JavaScript escape() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp)

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion mucio